# Setting a button at the bottom without textview going with it

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my button I have set it to the bottom succesfully but when I set it the textview I have goes down with it too all I want is the button only to be at the bottom and textview stay at its position which is center without following the position of the bottom I hope you can help me...

thanks in advance

this is my first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/first"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="10sp"
                    android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to button at bootm then try

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

instead of only gravity

in button and if you want to text center then

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Simply layout gravity assign your layout at perticular position and gavity assign it's content in perticular position in own layout

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is using `FrameLayout` and it's `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background2"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10sp"
                android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This solves the problem but this solution is not very flexible. If you want more flexibility for future changes, you could do a similar thing using `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 
-------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/lnrfirst"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10sp"
            android:text="قال (عليه السلام): (من كرمت عليه نفسه هانت عليه الدنيا)"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```